# Android MediaPlayer RTSP stream faster in lollipop than marshmallow; why?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, latency

I currently have a test app which plays a rtsp live stream from some other device via android's MediaPlayer object. Codes are as below;

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {

                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("test", "Exception", e);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Test", "Exception", e);
            }
```

It's nothing special, just a MediaPlayer object with a SurfaceView. This code works perfect in lollipop(galaxy s4), but somehow, there is about 2sec latency in marshmallow(galaxy s7).

Why is this happenning?

Is galaxy s7 a more enhanced edition compared to galaxy s4?

Comment: did you test it with same hardwares AVDs for these to version of OS?

Comment: I have to connect to a specific hardware through wifi, so I don't think testing through avd with my desktop is not possible. Though, I tested it in another galaxy s4 with a Kitkat, resulting the same latency of 2sec alike galaxy s7.

Comment: To add some more information, I tested it on another lolipop device(LG G2), but it showed about 2sec latency. I think there's something about the galaxy s4 lollipop, but can't figure it out.